# Is it bad practice to change views depending on the action?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I have a single controller, **Index**, that manages several non-specialized informational pages (e.g Homepage, Overview, Features, etc.). Each page has its own action in the controller. Depending on the action, a different View script is used to render the content.

Is it bad practice to use different View scripts to render each action? Should each page have its own controller? Thanks,

Comment: Read up on `Zend_Layout` and `Zend_View_Helpers`, you will almost never have to duplicate content over multiple view files, if that's what you are afraid of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is actually the standard best practice that Zend Framework MVC implements. That's how Zend Framework 'wants' you to do it! Why are you afraid it could be bad practice?

To your second way of asking...

> Should each page have its own controller?

No, but don't start thinking from the direction of pages, think in terms of **functional units**. For example, if your page needs **user management**, you will most likely have a `userController`.

What are the **functions** this controller needs to fulfill?

- Add users,
- delete users,
- let users edit their data,
- let users choose friends,
- etc.

So each of these functions becomes an action in your userController (function = method = action).

This way, you will automatically have easy to read URLs as well. And finally, every action has a .phtml view script, where the necessary markup for that action resides.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. I was just afraid that I was setting myself up for defeat by structuring my application that way.

Answer (score 3):

That's not bad practice at all. Consider a different scenario common to PHP applications. A CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) for Users.

All the actions should be on the same controller for Users.

I generally use:

- index - shows all the users
- add - create a new user
- edit - edit an existing user
- delete - delete a user (doesn't have a view just redirects).

It makes sense for add and edit to use the same view if appropriate, but there is no chance that add/edit could share the same view as index.